# Inherited Method running without call

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I am a new programmer beginning to work with GUIs in Java eclipse. I have this code (which I copy and pasted from a separate website) but am somewhat confused as to what is happening.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;  

import java.awt.Graphics;  
import java.awt.Color;  

public class DrawRectangleInJFrame extends JFrame  
{  
public DrawRectangleInJFrame()  
{  
 //Set JFrame title  
 super("Draw A Rectangle In JFrame");  

 //Set default close operation for JFrame  
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

 //Set JFrame size  
 setSize(400,400);  

 //Make JFrame visible   
 setVisible(true);  
}  

public void paint(Graphics g)  
{  
 super.paint(g);  

 //draw rectangle outline  
 g.drawRect(50,50,300,100);  

 //set color to RED  
 //So after this, if you draw anything, all of it's result will be RED  
 g.setColor(Color.RED);  

 //fill rectangle with RED  
 g.fillRect(50,50,300,100);  
}  

public static void main(String[]args)  
{  
 DrawRectangleInJFrame dlijf=new DrawRectangleInJFrame();  
}  
}
```

What I don't understand is when the paint method is run. Obviously, there is something happening in the JFrame class, but I feel if I understand what is happening I'll be able to work with it better.
Thanks!

Comment: The method is called internally by the JVM whenever it feels or your operating system feels that the component needs repainting. You can also suggest that it be called by calling `repaint()` on the component. Note that this code is not good as you should never override a JFrame's paint method for drawing but rather should override a JPanel's paintComponent method. Check out [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I have one other question if you don't mind. Is there any way for me to call the paintComponents method in another class to get it to draw the rectangle?

Comment: You never call paint or paintComponent directly. Instead you would give the other class a public method that the first class calls. In the public method, consider changing a boolean instance (non-static) field and then calling `repaint()`. The other class's paintComponent method can then use that boolean to decide if it wants to draw a rectangle.